# Change dtype for particular values in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array x, dimensions = (20, 4), in which only the first row and column are real string values (alphabets) and rest of the values are numerals with their types allocated as string. I want to change these numeral values to float or integer type.

I have tried some steps:

a. I made copies of first row and column of the array as separate variables:

```
x_row = x[0]
x_col = x[:,0]
```

Then deleted them from the original array `x` (using numpy.delete() method) and convertd the type of remaining values by applying a for loop that iterates over each value. However, when I stack back the copied rows and columns using `numpy.vstack()` and `numpy.hstack()`, then everything again converts to strings type. So, not sure why this is happening.

b. Same procedure as point a, except I used `numpy.insert()` method for inserting rows and columns, but is doing the same thing - converting everything back to string type.

So, is there a way through which I don't have to go through this deleting and stacking mechanism (which isn't working anyways) and I can change all the values (except first row and column) of an array to `int()` or `float()` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All items in a numpy array have to have the same dtype.  That is a fundamental fact about numpy.  You could possibly use a numpy recarray, or you could use `dtype=object` which basically lets all values be anything.

I'd recommend you take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), which provides a tabular data structure that allows different columns to have different types.  It sounds like what you have is a table with row and column labels, and that's what pandas deals with nicely.

Comment: You are absolutely right friend..haven't noticed that. I think rec array or dtype does my job (i.e. allocating the dtype of the array as object (dtype=object))... Also, never tried pandas arrays but read about them a bit. Thanks BrenBarn. :-)